# How to Import/Export user profiles in Edge browser

Tags: browser, microsoft-edge

I have multiple user profiles of test users and i would like to share it with my teammates, how can i do it in Edge browser?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to let others to use the test users' profiles and share the data in them with others, you can just provide the accounts and passwords and let others to login in with those accounts in their Edge browsers. This is the easiest way.

If you don't want to provide accounts and passwords to others, you can find the folder which stores each profile's data in *edge://version/*. You can navigate to *edge://version/*, find **Profile path**, that's the folder which stores profile data. You can share that folder with others.

[image]

Comment: tried to share the profile folder it didnt work, and sharing the passwords is not enough i would like to share all the profile configuration

Comment: Which kind of profile configuration do you want to share? You can provide some examples.

Comment: as I mentioned the profiles with all their data. we all use common users to test some scenarios so instead of making everyone configure it themselves if we find a way to export and import the profiles it would save us some time

Comment: I have tested and I found copy & paste profile folder can share all the data. For example, the profile folder you want to share is `C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\Default` on machine1. You can copy this folder and paste it on machine2 to replace the Default profile folder of machine2. Then when you open Edge on machine2, the default profile will be exactly the same as the default profile on machine1. All settings are the same.

Comment: I tried it, it didnt work for me, i cant see the profile i copied

Comment: You need to create a new profile in Edge first. Then find the newly created profile folder path and replace the folder with the profile folder you need. After this open Edge, you'll see the settings in the newly created profile have changed to the profile settings you copied. You can't see the copied profile if you don't create a new profile in Edge at first.

Comment: If I got you, you are saying that i need to create a new profile and past the content of the other profile (the shared one) to the created profile and it will work?, do you know which file contains the mapping to the profile folder? it would be easier to map it there as i have multiple profiles to handle

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. For the file contains mapping, as far as I know, there's no such file.